# Merging the tags complexity and complexity-theory

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

There are lots of questions tagged complexity-theory and only two tagged complexity. Presumably we should merge the latter into the former.

Comment: I manually retagged the questions tagged complexity.